# Samples of HibernateCursorItemReader with Spring-Batch 3.0.8 and Hibernate 5.x

Tags: hibernate, spring-batch

So drafting my first `Spring-Batch` app on `Spring-Boot 1.5.x`, and `Spring-Batch 3.0.8` using `Hibernate 5.x`.  The reference materials at spring.io are good; however, just about all the examples I have found are base on `Spring-JDBC` and not `Spring-Jpa/Hibernate`.  Also, most of the samples I have seen are much older using xml configs vs java configs.  So...Can some of you point me to 1 or more sample implementations that:
1.  Are on Spring-boot 1.4 or 5,
2.  Are on Spring-batch 3.0.x
3.  Use java configs and not xml
4.  Clearly illustrate how to construct the required `dataSource`, and `Session`
5.  Have a basic impl of the `HibernateCursorItemReader`

I am going to start hacking at it but I was hoping for some fairly current samples so as to shorting the amount of time I thrash about.  Appreciate it everybody.

Comment: Google is your friend here. Also note that the XML config for Spring Batch 3.0.x does not deviate far from any 2.x examples you may find.

Comment: Appreciate your response Dean.  As stated above, not much available on this topic so far. Lots and lots of JDBC impl examples but almost nothing using JPA/Hibernate.  I'm currently implementing something.  When I'm done, I'll post-up my solution.